# Allow to set NULL for datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(reader);
```

It calls an exception:

> System.Exception: 'Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows
>   contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key
>   constraints.'

Because in `reader` I get object with NULL element for column. How to allow for `DataGridView` to accept NULL cells values?

Comment: you give us so small information, we need to see a bigger part of code that we can try it.

Comment: You problem does not relate to DataGridView (WINFORMS), according to the exception. It relates to ADO.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, more information is needed about your particular issue to thoroughly answer your question but the following snippet will handle null values. Please be sure to check [this MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a92f86f2-5ee5-470e-88e2-af6565da88d8/datagridview-column-does-not-allow-null-values-prevent-row-being-automatically-removed?forum=winformsdatacontrols), and [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201058/how-to-enable-null-value-selection-in-datagridview-calendarcolumn) to find out if they are more relevant issues, and [this MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.nullvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) that could also be helpful given the general scope of your issue. It states:

> When a DataGridView cell with this cell style has a value of DBNull.Value or null or the user edits the cell and presses CTRL+0, the DataGridView control displays the NullValue property value. When a user edits a cell with this cell style and enters the value of this property or presses CTRL+0, the control sets the cell value to the value of the DataSourceNullValue property or to null if DataSourceNullValue is DBNull.Value and the cell ValueType is a reference type. This conversion does not occur when you set the DataGridViewCell.Value property programmatically.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
     String value = e.Value as string;
     if ((value != null) && value.Equals(e.CellStyle.DataSourceNullValue)) {
         e.Value = e.CellStyle.NullValue;
         e.FormattingApplied = true;
     }
}
```

Please be sure to do some heavy research and be thorough with your issue when posting so people can be more helpful.

For example, one could assume from looking at your code and the exception that it would be an issue with the table you're querying not allowing null values.

Comment: Error occurs at the time of filling the DataTable source, not after formatting data in table.